# Getting not equal entries where there are NULL entries

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Let us say we have 2 tables:

table0 : | colA | colB |

table1 : | colA | colB |

I would like the entries of colA which are different between the tables where the colB between the tables are the same. This is the query I am using:

```
SELECT table0.colA FROM table0, table1 WHERE table0.colB = table1.colB AND (table0.colA) <> (table1.colA)
```

This seems to work. But what if I have null values for colA in either tables?

- If the entry in colA for one table is null and is not for the other, I would like consider that to be a difference.
- if both entries in colA for both tables are null, I would like to consider that to be a difference.

How do I check for this? I tried using is ISNULL feature but that did not work properly when both entries are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is not going to select any rows when *either* table0.colA is null or table1.colA is null. (I no longer remember the explanation; it has become a "fact" over time). You can see this with a SELECT like

```
SELECT table0.colA, table1.colA,
CASE when table0.colA <> table1.colA then "true" else "false" END result
```

You'll need to use an OR conditional, something like

```
WHERE table0.colB = table1.colB 
AND (table0.colA <> table1.colA OR table0.colA is null OR table1.colA is null)
```

The `()` are significant, lest the first WHERE clause be "ignored". I am not familiar with `ISNULL` feature in SQLite3.